# Crawled property (Url) not trimmed

Tags: search, crawled-property

So this is a nice one, here is what I'm trying to do:
In a Content search webpart, I want to show all documents and links that match a certain filter, using a Content Search Webpart. The result needs to be sorted alphabetically.

To make this work I placed a Content Search WebPart on a page, applied the required filter and set the sort order to Title (ascending)

I noticed that the link items got sorted alphabetically, but seperately from the documents. After research, I figured it was because there is a leading space in the title for Link items. Example:

- A (Link item)
- C (Link item)
- E (Link item)
- B (Document)
- D (Document)
- F (Document)

Since the different browsers I tried all visually omit the leading space, it was hard to spot what was going on.

The root cause of this problem is because in the Link list item, the URL field is stored with the URL and description in one field in the following format: ows_URL='{url}, {descrption}' example: ows_URL='http://google.com, Google'
Notice the space after the comma? The search crawler is smart enough to not index ows_URL literally (it omits the url), but leaves the leading space.

How can I get rid of the leading space in the search results, so I can sort by title?

Comment: You should not need to add the ows_Url field to title (I wouldn't, Title is used in too many places.) The Description part of the URL should (IIRC) already be present in the Title field, but it has been a while since I looked. Have you tried this by creating a new MP instead?

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed not neccesary to add ows_Url to the mapped property Title. I reformulated the answer. I still can't get rid of the leading spaces, which mess up my sorting.

Comment: If it's a bug, you should report it. Another workaround could be to fix it with content processing.

Comment: Customer decided to go along with content processing, as suggested by Matthew and other experts in my network.